# how to get a user structure known only his email Firebase Realtime

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database that contains a child "users". This child has different users. 
Each user has a bunch of attributes like this: user(email,name,age,phonenumber,gender).

I've separated them using the push function with an unique generated ID: 
[image: RealtimeDatabase2é]

So my problem is: I want to get all the attributes of a specific user known that I only have his email address.

I have tried this query but I don't know how it works exactly

```
    reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email
```

Comment: Assuming that `reference` is a DatabaseReference pointing to your User node, this query should work just fine. What result are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :-

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            String age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String.class);
            String fullName = dataSnapshot.child("fullName").getValue(String.class);
            String gender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue(String.class);
            String phone_number = dataSnapshot.child("phone_number").getValue(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", "error is " + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Please go through this link, to learn more about retrieving data from Firebase

[Retrieving Data From Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

Comment: Looping over all child nodes in the client to find the one with the matching email address is not needed (and incredibly wasteful of the user's bandwidth). `databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addChildEventListener` will solve that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh, didn't think about the performance, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

To display that data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String age = ds.child("age").getValue(String.class);
            //and so on
            Log.d("TAG", name + " / " + age);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

This is an example for displaying in your logcat the `name` and `age`. In the same way you can also get there other values.